# Reset a Modal View Controller

Tags: objective-c, modalviewcontroller

I have a modal view controller that initiates a process. If I dismiss the modal view controller, then reopen it, it continues from where it left off. What I want is to (upon dismissal) reset the modal view controller, cancel all processing and reset it to it's initial state. Is there a way?

Cheers

Comment: put a check on session initialization, if already is there, destroy it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't save the `UIViewController` subclass object in an ivar, just `alloc] init]` a new one every time you want to present one.

Answer (score 2):

sorry if I'll say something obvious, but I spent some of time to figure out how to do this:

> Don't save the `UIViewController` subclass object in an ivar, just `alloc] init]` a new one every time you want to present one.

In my case I have this code in MasterViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ContactsDetailViewController *detailViewController;
```

and this one in MasterViewController.m

```
@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;

if (!self.detailViewController) {
self.detailViewController = [[ContactsDetailViewController alloc] 
            initWithNibName:@"ContactsDetailViewController" 
            bundle:nil];
}
```

You should delete this code and use next code in place, where you pushing your modal view controller:

```
ContactsDetailViewController *detailViewController = [[ContactsDetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ContactsDetailViewController" bundle:nil];
detailViewController.title = @"View Controller"; // for example
[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
```

note: I'm using ARC in this project

Hope it will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

IN the viewDidUnload method of the viewController for your modal view, try stopping the task.